# Why delete default copy and move ctor and assignment for base classes?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why delete default copy and move ctor and assignment for base classes?

This is from Stroustrup's book (4-th edition c++).

Usually base classes are abstract so why would you worry about that at all,
when you can't even instantiate them.

Comment: "Usually base classes are abstract" Please back up this claim with evidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation you are trying to avoid:

```
 class A
 {
 };

 class B : public A
 {
 };

 class C : public A
 {
   int foo;
 };
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    A* c_ptr = new C();
    A* b_ptr = new B();

    *b_ptr = *c_ptr;//unless you explictly dissalow this, it can be done!
 }
```

Comment: So as a rule, I should always delete default copy for base classes that I don't plan to instantiate?

Comment: @user311311: Whether or not you can instantiate the base class is hardly relevant.

Comment: Disallowing copy also prevents this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Answer (score 0):

The answer is twofold; one is a matter of semantics and the other is a matter of practicality in C++.

Value types are interchangeable, a specific instance is not relevant, they should be copyable and assignable and act like regular types.  Examples might include a specific date, the value of pi, a name, a colour.

Reference types represent an instance of a thing; the specific instance is relevant, it's not just a description of a thing.  Semantically, it doesn't make sense to allow copying of these.  Examples might include a person, a file, a thread.

Types that are polymorphic in C++ are reference types; they must be passed by reference (or pointer) in order to maintain the correct behaviour.  In practice, copy constructors are not polymorphic; copying through a base reference can lead to slicing, and thus a change in behaviour, which is a very poor representation of a copy.  It is quite popular to introduce a virtual method to allow "cloning" of the polymorphic type.

The question suggested base classes should be non-copyable and non-assignable, but in fact, it is only base classes that are intended to be used polymorphically where this applies.

There are occasions where a class is designed to be inherited from, but it is not designed to be used poymorphically; for example, boost::noncopyable and CRTP classes.  In this case it also makes sense to prevent instances of classes derived from them to be held by reference to the base; usually by reducing the visibility of the constructor or destructor by making one or both of them protected or private.  These classes do not require a virtual destructor.